# How to create a point cloud from DEM?

Tags: dem, 3d-model

Please forgive my ignorance if I am asking a totally irrelevant question, I am still a GIS newbie.
I looked in Google and found a lot of links as of how to convert point clouds to DEMs.

I am trying to achieve exactly an opposite:
to create a point cloud from a DEM of the specific location and then 
to create a 3D model of this location from this point cloud.

I didn't find one single link about it.

So is all my thinking wrong? Is there other way to achieve what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FME can [do a raster to point cloud transformation](http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/Samples_and_Demos/Creating-Point-Clouds-from-3D-models-or-rasters). It's certainly not a typical operation but as the link points out, there are some potential applications.

Answer (score 8):

You might not find good solutions, because a Point Cloud and DEM are used for two different things.

A Point Cloud represents the point of returns from usually a LIDAR survey. At a given (X,Y) point, there can be multiple points at different heights. Imagine a Single Tree. You will get the return points from both the Canopy, as well as the ground underneath it. Or Alternatively, image the points representing the Side of a building. You will have multiple points at the same (X,Y) location.

Compared to this, DEM raster is much simpler. It will have only one elevation value for a given cell. A Cell does not exactly represent a (X,Y) point either, since it has a cell width and cell height. Hence a Cell is not the exact equivalent of a point.

So if in some way you create a point cloud from a DEM, it really won't be an accurate representation of reality; Additionally it won't be equal to what a real point cloud of that location will be like.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really use QGIS or Grass, but the process would simply be a matter of creating a point at the centroid of each pixel in the raster.  I just don't know what the tool is, or if there is one.  This may help [http://www.slideshare.net/shencoop/qgis-raster-to-pointCreating](http://www.slideshare.net/shencoop/qgis-raster-to-point), it makes sense creating an ascii file from the raster and then using those values as the coordinates and then whatever the pixel value is. a TIN from a raster would would be creating a node for each of the triangles at the center of each pixel, in principle doing the same thing but adding a lot of extra data.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is very old, but I needed this functionality and did not find anything I was happy with. I wrote my own python function using numpy and rasterio, maybe it helps someone at some point:

```py
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np

def raster_to_cloud(rasterPath, outfile=None):

    raster = rio.open(rasterPath, "r")
    
    affineTrafo = raster.transform
    noDataVal = raster.get_nodatavals()[0]

    trafoMat = np.array([[affineTrafo[0],affineTrafo[1],affineTrafo[2]],
                         [affineTrafo[3],affineTrafo[4],affineTrafo[5]],
                         [0,0,1]])

    zVals = np.squeeze(raster.read())
    noDataMask = np.array(zVals.reshape(-1)!=noDataVal)

    myMesh = np.array(np.meshgrid(np.arange(zVals.shape[0]), np.arange(zVals.shape[1]), np.array([1]), indexing="ij"))
    myMesh = np.squeeze(myMesh).transpose(1,2,0).reshape(-1,3)[noDataMask,:]

    zVals = zVals.reshape(-1)[noDataMask]

    myMesh = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.matmul(trafoMat, x), axis=-1, arr=myMesh)
    myMesh[:,2] = zVals

    if outfile:
        np.savetxt(outfile, myMesh)

    return myMesh
```

This should work, but no guarantees of course.

Answer (score 0):

which GIS do you use?
For ESRI Arc solutions, there is a simple tutorial for creating a 3d model:
[TUTORIAL(PDF)](http://crl.ap.buffalo.edu/digitalworkshop/zcorp/pdfs/Creating%203D%20Models%20Using%20ArcGIS.pdf)

Before the first step (Shape to TIN) you need to generate either contour lines from your raster (spatial analysis > contour) or a TIN directly from your raster (3d analyst > raster to TIN)

EDIT: If you necessarely need points, try the [Raster to Points tool in the ArcGIS toolbox](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Raster%20to%20Point%20%28Conversion%29)

Comment: I was planning to use QGIS/GRASS. Is it possible with these tools?